# Can I setup a remote spark server inside docker so that I can communicate with it locally?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-spark, docker, pyspark

I already install a docker image on Amazon EC2:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge lxc-docker
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)
sudo apt-get install apparmor
sudo apt-get install docker-engine
sudo service docker start
sudo docker pull sequenceiq/spark
sudo docker run -d $(sudo docker images|tail -n 1|awk '{print $3}')
```

And it runs successfully:

```
$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                                                   NAMES
0596a52cb11b        016b4fce9cd0        "/etc/bootstrap.sh -d"   58 minutes ago       Up 58 minutes        22/tcp, 8030-8033/tcp, 8040/tcp, 8042/tcp, 8088/tcp, 49707/tcp, 50010/tcp, 50020/tcp, 50070/tcp, 50075/tcp, 50090/tcp   ecstatic_noether
```

Questions:

1. `http://<instance public IP>:<ports listed above>` does not work. What am I missing?
2. is it possible to connect to this instance and do the jobs on my laptop with `pyspark`?

Thank you.

(I read [Running Spark on EC2](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ec2-scripts.html) but it is not for docker)